# Marshal - Do I need to free any resources?

Tags: c#, bitmap, marshalling

I am using below method to convert `byte[]` to `Bitmap`:

```
    public static Bitmap ByteArrayToBitmap(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        int width = 2144;
        int height = 3;
        Bitmap bitmapImage = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        BitmapData bmpData = bitmapImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        try
        {
            Marshal.Copy(byteArray, 0, ptr, byteArray.Length);
            bitmapImage.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            return bitmapImage;
        }
        finally
        {
           //Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr); //Do I need this?
        }
    }
```

Just wondering if I need to free up any resources here?
Tried calling `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr)`, but I am getting this error:

> Invalid access to memory location.

Can anyone please guide?

Also, FYI, I could use `MemoryStream` to get `Bitmap` out of `byte[]`, but I was getting 'Parameter not valid' exception in that case. That's why took the route to `Marshal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you should do is be sure you call dispose on the returned `Bitmap`. The best way to do that is placing it within `using` block.

```
using(Bitmap myBitmap = ByteArrayToBitmap(someArray)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Umm are you sure about that, you are disposing the object that is being returned.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You're right, I missed that. I tried to delete the answer, but you cannot delete accepted answer...

Comment: I see what you where trying to do with your edit, I made some more changes to make it more clear hopefully. If I was wrong please roll back.

Answer (score 4):

You only use FreeHGlobal when you used AllocHGlobal.  You didn't so don't call it.  You did allocate unmanaged memory, it was done by `new Bitmap`.  That's released by Dispose() or the GC.  Later.

You certainly should use that finally block, that's where you call UnlockBits().  That 'releases' the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need to.

The memory that is allocated for the bitmap is allocated by the Bitmap constructor and it will be freed when the bitmapImage gets disposed.